# Spring boot with Jersey - Filter request body properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jersey

I would like to know if there is some way to filter the properties of an object that a resource receives.

Let me explain myself: lets say we have this object:

UserDTO

```
public final class IniciativaDocument {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String address;
    private Double balance;
}
```

And for a resource I only need the properties "name" and "surname" but for other I only need "address" and "id". Is there any way to make the unneeded variables null automatically with something like Jackson?

My goal for this is that if the client sends a request with a field that isn't needed that I don't have to make it null before saving it to the database because that field is not supposed to be initialized when registering.

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

For more clarity: this is for a matter of security and easiness.

Imagine I am a hacker and somehow know the fields a `DTO` class has. I could easily send a `POST` request like this to a service which is to register users:

```
{
   "id": "wrong",
   "name": "Wrong",
   "balance": 20000
}
```

For my service I would only need `id` and `name` but the hacker is sending a `balance` field too.

What I want to do is that as I receive this object, I can set my endpoint `/api/v1/users` (which is to register) to put any initialized field that isn't `id` or `name` to `null`.

You might say I could just make sure it's 0 or set it to null manually. Yeah, that's true, but I want to find out if there's an automatic and more comfortable way of doing this with annotations or something similar.

**EDIT 2**

Resource example:

```
@Component
@Path("iniciativas")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public final class IniciativasEndpoint {
    @POST
    public Response crearIniciativa(@Valid @NotNull(message = CONSTRAINT_BODY_NOT_NULL) @ConvertGroup(to = IniciativasGroup.Create.class)
                                        final IniciativaDTO iniciativaDTO,
                                    @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {

        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Jackson's JsonIgnore Property` for this like:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public final class IniciativaDocument {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String address;
}
```

So Basically what it does is, when it is mapping this class to `Json` it will ignore all fields with `null` value. And if you want it not to apply on whole class you can do it on fields as well.

AND If you want to achieve it through `front-end` then you can use this great api [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/), so basically in request you will specify what fields you require and it will return only those fields.

Comment: I don't want it to ignore null fields. I want the possibility to say this "for the service at /api/v1/users I will only need the fields 'name' and 'surname', if there is any other field with a value, set them to null"

Comment: It will automatically set them to null if it doesn't find the value for these fields so for example you send a post request when only name and surname the other fields will be null by default

Comment: That's not what I mean. I made an edit to try to clarify it my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use a post-matching filter:
You can implement `ContainerRequestFilter` and annotate your Filter with `@PostMaching` (javax.ws.rs.container.PreMatching) and manipulate the your request with its data there.

Define an @interface for your Filter:

```
@NameBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
public @interface AnnotationForYourFilter {}
```

Annotate the sub-resource you want with @AnnotationForYourFilter and you are done.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to figure out how to make it work this way. Could you make an easy example, please?

Comment: I will do that tomorrow as it's now 17:00 localtime and I have off.

Comment: Do you still need help?

Comment: OK. Let me know what you have as resource and endpoints (sub-resources)

Comment: In your `crearIniciativa` sub-resource, you await an `IniciativaDocument`-object and you don't need to control the values of (`id`, `name`, `surname`, `address`, `balance`) but in another sub-resource (you didn't show) you await ... what?

Comment: IniciativaDocument belongs to the persistence layer. What I am expecting is IniciativaDTO which has the same values and then I just map it using ModelMapper. I don't think this matters, I put IniciativaDocument just as an example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194178/discussion-between-meziane-and-wrong).